# Trying to convert C code to C++ - interative binary Euclidean algorithm

Tags: c++, c, debugging, greatest-common-divisor

I tried to convert some code from C to C++, please could you guys let me know where I've gone wrong and give me some pointers? thanks

For some reason every time someone asks a trivialish question like this they get told "do your own homework" etc, so I'll just point out that this isn't homework, for what it's worth. Thanks again

```
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int gcd_bin(int u, int v)
    {
        int t, k;

        u = u < 0 ? -u : u; /* abs(u) */
        v = v < 0 ? -v : v;
        if (u < v)
        {
            t = u;
            u = v;
            v = t;
        }
        if (v == 0)
            return u;

        k = 1;
        while (u & 1 == 0 && v & 1 == 0)
        { /* u, v - even */
            u >>= 1; v >>= 1;
            k <<= 1;
        }

        t = (u & 1) ? -v : u;
        while (t)
        {
            while (t & 1 == 0)
                t >>= 1;

            if (t > 0)
                u = t;
            else
                v = -t;

            t = u - v;
        }

        return u * k;
    }
}
```

Comment: What problems are you having with this code? What happens, and what do you expect to happen? What question are you actually asking? ("Please fix my code" doesn't count.)

Comment: Is the only thing in `main` a function definition? Also, most C code is valid C++, and there does not look like much to "convert".

Comment: C++ is almost a perfect superset of C, so there is not much to port. The code you posted isn't valid C however (the nested functions in particular).

Comment: It's an iterative binary version of the extended Euclidean algorithm, maybe posting the original code would help?

Comment: I think your problem is that you are trying to post a function definition inside of main, try moving the function out then make a call to it inside of main like `gcd_bin(2,4);`

Comment: Hint: C++ doesn't support nested functions (and no, lambdas don't doubt)

Comment: Thanks, wow I feel like an idiot, thanks a lot

Answer (score 1):

I don't yet have an answer to accept but the problem has bee resolved by people pointing out how stupid I was being in the comments, thanks again.

EDIT: I posted this so I could accept it as an answer and close the question, it doesn't let me accept it for another two days.

Comment: It's OK to post and accept your own answer, but please edit and make it one then. Put your corrections in the code you made here (concisely).